# How to import blank/NULL fields into Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2017

Tags: dynamics-nav

I'm using Configuration Packages in Dynamics NAV 2017, and exporting/importing Excel files to update table data. This has worked fine in most circumstances, but I have a table with a column of data I want to clear out/erase. The column needs to be there but should have no values.

I've tried exporting my table with the column, removing the existing values and re-importing with the column totally blank. That doesn't work as everything is still there.

Is there a special character or some other way to overwrite values with nulls?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work to use a character like 0 or hyphen or a word like None or Nothing since blanks don't seem to work?

Comment: Tried using 0 and NULL but neither worked. The field refers to the PK of a related table